# webhp в адресе google.com - что это?

Tags: https

В адресах веб-страниц после имени сайта указывается путь к файлу или папке. Вот к примеру для гугл полный путь это `https://www.google.com/index.html`
А что тогда за webhp вот в этом адресе `https://www.google.com/webhp`
Это не каталог, потому что если поставить слэш в конце, то будет 404 ошибка, это не html файл, не php. Я не понимаю, что это такое и какого оно расширения, раз это не каталог. И почему в путях могут быть файлы без расширения. Как это возможно? Пожалуйста, объясните.

Comment: В путях может быть всё что угодно. Эти пути не имеют абсолютно никакого отношения к файлам. Пути попадают на сервер и сервер решает, основываясь на своем маппинге, как такие пути обрабатывать. Поэтому часто имеет значение есть ли в конце слеш или нет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ